# Iam user can not see any bucket on s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I use root user to create bucket call `xxx`, I also create IAM user. When I login by IAM user, I access S3 and see error:

```
You don't have permissions to list buckets
After you or your AWS administrator have updated your permissions to allow the s3:ListAllMyBuckets action, refresh this page. Learn more about Identity and access management in Amazon S3
```

I try create policy like below on IAM and attach for my IAM user. But I still have error? Why IAM user can not access s3. I also add `AmazonS3FullAccess` permission for IAM user.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListStorageLensConfigurations",
                "s3:ListAccessPointsForObjectLambda",
                "s3:GetAccessPoint",
                "s3:PutAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:ListAccessPoints",
                "s3:ListJobs",
                "s3:PutStorageLensConfiguration",
                "s3:CreateJob"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::xxx"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: There are other types of policies that could affect your user, such as a resource-based policy on the bucket or SCP policies or permission boundaries. Assuming none of these are in effect, you should be using `s3:ListBuckets` in your custom policy. If you've attached the "AmazonS3FullAccess" policy to the user and there are no other policies denying access, then the user will be able to see the bucket. If the user can't then you've done something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I has the same error because i forget to add the administrators a group user by signing in as a root user email, then sign as iam , it should be good to go.